# Weight of labeled data in samples for decision trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I am trying to do some binary decision trees with Python (scikit-learn), but my sample has a bad repartition : I have something like 100 000 data points with label 0 and 800 000 with the label 1.

So when I get the tree, I don't have a lot of leaves with class 0, and I don't even have any before reaching a depth of 5. And in that node, there are very few points.

I also tried trees with other variables (still the same labels) and I get more data with label 0 ; the problem is that I am not sure this makes sense.

What could I do ? Should I take a sample of my data with 50% of each label? I am afraid doing that won't really be representative of my data, especially if I put new data in the tree afterwhat.
Does anyone know what are the requirements for samples for decision trees? I didn't find any information anywhere about it.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Marie

Comment: I am afraid that this question might be too broad for this forum but https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a dataset has significantly more data points belonging to one class, than to another, it is called *imbalanced*. Your dataset is imbalanced.
Your have 8 times less data points in minority class than in your majority class.

The simplest (and correct) way to handle this with sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier is to set parameter

```
class_weight="balanced"
```

From my experience, this helps a lot. 
With this setting, each data point from your minority class will be given a weight 8. This means, roughly speaking, it will be considered 8 times more important than any point from the majority class.

See more details in the scikit-learn [DecisionTreeClassifier documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) and feel free to educate yourself further in 'imbalanced learning'.